# Parallel accounts (Day 2)

Tags: code-golf

<sup>Challenge Taken with permission from my University Code Challenge Contest</sup>

---

After finishing her studies a couple of months ago, Marie opened a bank account to start receiving the payment of her first job in town. Since then she has been performing a few transactions with it. Her first payment was $1000 dollars. With that money she paid for a dinner in which she invited her parents (The dinner cost $150 dollars), then, she did a purchase in a well-known supermarket ($80 dollars) and a hotel reservation for her vacations ($200). At the end of the month she received her payment again (1040 dollars, a little more than the previous month) and the day after she spent another $70 dollars at the supermarket.

Today, she realized that if after paying the first $80 dollars in the supermarket a second account had been created and the first one frozen, both accounts would have exactly the same balance:

$$ \underbrace{1000\quad -150\quad -80}_{Total=770}\quad \underbrace{-200\quad 1040\quad -70}_{Total=770} $$

The event was so rare to her that she wants to continue ascertaining if the movements of her account and those of her friends have also this feature or not.

**Challenge**

Given a list of transactions, output the number of instants of time in which the owner of the bank account could have created a second account so that both had the same final balance.

**Example:** `[1000, -150, -80, -200, 1040, -70]`
$$ \color{red}{1)\quad\underbrace{}_{Total=0}\quad \underbrace{1000\quad -150\quad -80\quad -200\quad 1040\quad -70}_{Total=1540}} $$
$$ \color{red}{2)\quad\underbrace{1000}_{Total=1000}\quad \underbrace{-150\quad -80\quad -200\quad 1040\quad -70}_{Total=540}} $$
$$ \color{red}{3)\quad\underbrace{1000\quad -150}_{Total=850}\quad \underbrace{-80\quad -200\quad 1040\quad -70}_{Total=690}} $$
$$ \color{green}{4)\quad\underbrace{1000\quad -150\quad -80}_{Total=770}\quad \underbrace{-200\quad 1040\quad -70}_{Total=770}} $$
$$ \color{red}{5)\quad\underbrace{1000\quad -150\quad -80\quad-200}_{Total=570}\quad \underbrace{ 1040\quad -70}_{Total=970}} $$
$$ \color{red}{6)\quad\underbrace{1000\quad -150\quad -80\quad -200\quad 1040}_{Total=1610}\quad \underbrace{-70}_{Total=-70}} $$
$$ \color{red}{7)\quad\underbrace{1000\quad -150\quad -80\quad-200\quad 1040\quad -70}_{Total=1540}\quad \underbrace{}_{Total=0}} $$

**Test Case**

- Input: `1000 -150 -80 -200 1040 -70` Output: `1`
- Input: `100 -100` Output: `2`
- Input: `1 2 3` Output: `1`
- Input: `10 -20 15` Output: `0`
- Input: `15 -15 15 -15` Output: `3`
- Input: `1` Output: `0`

**Notes**

- You can assume there wont be any transaction of $0 dollars
- You can take input in [any reasonable way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: After 6 months of frozen and newly created accounts, it is reported that Marie's banker is now interned in a sanitarium. "We are your friends. You need some rest", they said.

Comment: Suggested test case of a single transaction

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 63 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Append(0).Where((a,b)=>n.Take(b).Sum()*2==n.Sum()).Count()
```

Saved 6 bytes thanks to dana

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBCoMwDIbve4rSUwLaVTfZYFYYg512EBR21q4ymati6/O7OmGwox6S/CH8H0mk8aWpx@ugZXyrjY1rbRNvSpUYtUg0O3ed0g/gyO5P1SuAwitxGuTFS0GJLBvegELoWWxDZJd20BZwPG3S3qGgAhpwzokfRC4dXYSuC/jeqQOnLOua2gIl1MFUo6QFKRJnZGnRGwUSkeXttB0g4j/UMfmPsNROQrJb6/0eQYJorT@avkHmsogxfgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{+grep .sum/2,[\+] 0,|$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYKvwv1o7vSi1QEGvuDRX30gnOkY7VsFAp0Ylvva/NVdxIkiVho2hgYGBgq6hKZCwAGIjIM/QwATIMjew00RRBlRlgCqmYKRgjKoIZICCoSmKoCnIeAUIBZT4DwA)

## Explanation

We just prepend a zero to the given list (`0,|$_`), make a sequence of partial sums with `[\+]` (i. e. the sequence formed by the first element, the sum of first two, the sum of first three etc.), and look (`grep`) for any elements that are exactly equal to the half of the final account state (sum of the given list). Finally, we count them with a `+`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0.ø.œ2ùO€ËO
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fQO/wDr2jk40O7/R/1LTmcLf////RhgYGOrpAIhYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/A73DO/SOTjY6vNP/UdOaw93@/3X@R0cbGhgY6OgamgIJCyA2AvIMDUyALHODWB0FkDRQ1gDC1jHSMYYIghTqGJqCOaYg7ToQKjYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
0.ø          # Surround the (implicit) input list with a leading and trailing 0
             #  i.e. [100,-100] → [0,100,-100,0]
   .œ        # Get all possible partitions to divide the list
             #  → [[[0],[100],[-100],[0]],[[0],[100],[-100,0]],[[0],[100,-100],[0]],[[0],[100,-100,0]],[[0,100],[-100],[0]],[[0,100],[-100,0]],[[0,100,-100],[0]],[[0,100,-100,0]]]
     2ù      # Only leave partitions consisting of 2 items
             #  → [[[0],[100,-100,0]],[[0,100],[-100,0]],[[0,100,-100],[0]]]
       O     # Take the sum of each
             #  → [[0,0],[100,-100],[0,0]]
        €Ë   # Check of each inner list if both sums are equal (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
             #  → [1,0,1]
          O  # Take the sum of that (and output as result)
             #  → 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 6 bytes

```
ŻÄḤ=SS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7sMtD3cssQ0O/n@4/VHTGvf//6OjDQ0MDHQUdA1NQaQFiDACCRgamIDY5gaxOlwKIEUgNQZQno6CkY6CMVQGrAOowRTCNwUbBuKDGbGxAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

```javascript
a=>!a.map(v=>o[s+=v]=-~o[s],s=0,o=[1])|o[s/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BDsIgEETvfgXeIEJdUKKX7Y8QDqS2RtOWRgwn468j1KN4mczO28ncXXShe9yWp5j9pU8DJoft1jWTW2jE1puww2hRvLOzPCBwj0Za9sr3XtnU@Tn4sW9Gf6UDNRIAOBFSFz0XUSWQcCz@BJaxzW@lNKDKOFGcHKqtjL5TNapXkof135d1MH0A)

Save 4 bytes by using `-~o[s]`. Thanks to Shaggy.

Comment: +1 for beating Arnauld :o

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY3BDsIgEETvfgVHSKEuVaKX7Y8QDqS2RlO7jRhOxl9H0HiSy2R23k7m6qMPw/2yPtRCpzFNmDz2jW9vfuURe7KhwehQvbJzMiBIQqudeOZ727k00BJoHtuZznziVgOAZEqbosciXQk07Is/gBNi818pDagyyTrJdtVWRt@pGjUfkofN7yW9AQ)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, Arnauld ain't (always) unbeatable! ;)

Comment: @Shaggy leading `+` is changed to `!`, so it could work for input `[100]`.

Comment: Ah, didn't realise we had to handle singleton arrays. Nicely fixed.

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY1BDsIgEEX3noIlRKgDSupmehHCgtTWaGqnEcPSqyPUpXXz8zNvXv49pBD75215qZkuQx4xB@w4odNeuNA8wsITduTiHpNH9S7Ny4ggZDwYn3uaI01DM9GVj9xpAJBMaVvzXMPUg4ZT7S14IXa/SjVgk0lmJDtuWgV9p7aoXUkZtn9f1sH8AQ) if _undefined_ instead of \$0\$ is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>n+=(s+=x)==eval(a.join`+`)-s,n=s=0)|n+!s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3LCsIwEEX3fkXcJeTBpFp0M/0RETrUVFrapBgpXfjvsVFc2c1lmHMPt6eZYvPopqf24eZSi4mwIjPSxBesvEQeJS4C0c00cDJ96Hwta6Gj8hgRxMvLfUxN8DEMzgzhzlt@sQCgmLZlznOOIj8sHPN9gqsQu38lG7DJFCsUO2xaK/pObdHyQ9bh8ldJbw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                        // a[] = input array
  a.map(x =>                // for each element x in a[]:
    n +=                    //   increment n if the following test is truthy:
      (s += x)              //     update the left sum
      ==                    //     and test whether it's equal to
      eval(a.join`+`) - s,  //     the right sum
    n = s =0                //   start with n = s = 0
  )                         // end of map()
  | n                       // yield n; if the final sum is 0, it means that we could have
  +                         // created a balanced account at the beginning of the process;
  !s                        // so, we increment n if it is
```

---

## Recursive version,  <s>54</s>  53 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,s=0)=>a+a?(s==eval(a.join`+`))+f(a,s+a.pop()):!s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3RCoJAEEXf@wp7m2FXGa2lCLY@JAIH01DEkTb8/c0pempfLsOce7gDLxyaZz@/8knubYydB7bBE/ozG75A8L5deAQuBumn2tSIptOK4WKWGRBP2xAbmYKMbTHKAzq4lkRks7x0mkeNSh8l7fU@0A1x86@oQUlms8pmu6S1ou9UiroPWYfdrxLf)

Comment: I was just about to suggest that 52-byte version!

Comment: @Shaggy Yeah, I discarded the non-recursive version too soon because I thought the recursive one could be shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function

```apl
+/⊂((+/↑)=1⊥↓)¨⍨0,⍳∘≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X1v/UVeThgaQapuoaWv4qGvpo7bJmodWPOpdYaDzqHfzo44ZjzoX/U971DbhUW/fo76pnv6PupoPrTcGqgfygoOcgWSIh2fw/zQFQwMDA4VD6w1NQaQFiDACChgamICY5gZcYBUgBQZgtoKRgjFYDKxQwdAUxDEFGwCjAQ)

`⍳` **ɩ**ndices
 `∘` of
`≢` the tally of transactions

`0,` prepend zero

`⊂(`…`)¨⍨` apply the following tacit function with each of those as left argument and the entire list of transactions as right argument (`⍨` swaps argument

`⊂` the entire list of transactions
 `(`…`)` as left argument to the below function
  `¨` applied to each of the indices
   `⍨` with swapped arguments (i.e. list on right, indices on left:

`↓` drop that many from the left

`1⊥` sum (lit. evaluate in base-1)

`(`…`)=` is it (0/1) equal to…

`↑` take that many transactions from the left

`+/` sum them

`+/` sum that Boolean list to get the count of truths

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-x`, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
iT å+ ®¥nUx
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=aVQg5SsgrqVuVXg=&input=WzEwMDAgLTE1MCAtODAgLTIwMCAxMDQwIC03MF0KLXg=)

```
iT å+ ®¥nUx     :Implicit input of array U
i               :Prepend
 T              :  Zero
   å+           :Cumulatively reduce by addition
      ®         :Map each Z
       ¥        :  Test for equality with
        n       :  Z subtracted from
         Ux     :  U reduced by addition
                :Implicitly reduce by addition and output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>67</s> 58 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(sum(l[:x])*2==sum(l)for x in range(len(l)+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/RCoIwFIbvfYqD3biasM2kEOxFbBerZgpzii6wp7edZUKDHc6@/@c/Z8PbNb3Nlrq8LkZ1t4cCU0yvLsFrqmKWZC/KMrxI3Y8wQ2thVPapE6OthwdOyIKK05O7q0mjoYrAn4ozxiikPMd6xiIQcHbE/sQkhR3wzYtW9oVihRQEhezfF2J8Sh4wW3EeBiEOjfRSFskiqMPYWpf8FqQQp5eYQr0R/4MP)

*-9 bytes thanks to @Don't be a x-triple dot*

Comment: Summing instead of filtering will save you 7 bytes: `lambda l:sum(sum(l[:x])==sum(l[x:])for x in range(len(l)+1))`.

Comment: `sum(l[:x])*2==sum(l)` saves you another 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>50</s> 37 bytes

```r
sum(c(0,cumsum(x<-scan()))==sum(x)/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NCsIwEIX3nmKgmwwkOEktirRL156hBCMBk0qbgCCePSYtSgUX8/e@NzNjMtAKMNHrYAfPLMITJt377iuhherk4q0P1l9nBmYYIVymIqQpOqYZcR1daR@tKBaGiF03C7hVmF4bk12SiLiQTU6HHCpPkna52xNiBecY7jEcQX7M2Us/RC2EK17/WygnuWzWiBbUlLd8KWtcpzc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

*@NahuelFouilleul saves a byte*

```perl
y/ /+/;$\+=eval$'==eval$`while/^|$|\+/g}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79SX0FfW99aJUbbNrUsMUdF3RZCJ5RnZOak6sfVqNTEaOun11b//29oqqALxBDqX35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDg/@6BQA)

Comment: `y/ /+/;` saves 1 byte

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n1upUmH9XyXeNr0otaBaJV7LyNa2uDTXwa02N7FApULbViVex0DHwe3/f0MDAwMFXUNTIGEBxEZAnqGBCZBlbsBlCJYyADIUjBSMgVyQvIKhKZehKUiLAoT6l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQ4L9uYkEOkOOTWVxiZRVakpkDshoA) using other approach

Comment: [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n1upUmH9XyXeNr0otaDaSEtDpULbViVe09a2uDTXwa3WQMfB7f9/QwMDAwVdQ1MgYQHERkCeoYEJkGVuwGUIljIAMhSMFIyBXJC8gqEpl6EpSIsChPqXX1CSmZ9X/F/X11TPwNDgv25iQQ6Q45NZXGJlFVqSmQOyEAA)

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 84 bytes

```
@set s=%*
@set/as=%s: =+%,c=0
@for %%n in (0 %*)do @set/as-=%%n*2,c+=!s
@echo %c%
```

Takes input as command-line arguments. Explanation:

```
@set s=%*
```

Join the arguments with spaces.

```
@set/as=%s: =+%,c=0
```

Replace the spaces with `+`s and evaluate the result. Also clear the count.

```
@for %%n in (0 %*)do @set/as-=%%n*2,c+=!s
```

For each amount, subtract double that from the sum. If the result is zero, then this is a valid match, so increment the count. The extra zero at the beginning allows for a match before any amounts.

```
@echo %c%
```

Print the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 15 bytes

```
⊞θ⁰ＩΣＥθ⁼Σθ⊗Σ✂θκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gtDhDo1BHwUDTmiugKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8M3sQAk41pYmphTDBYp1NRRcMkvTcpJTQHzg3Myk1NBarI1ocD6///oaEMDAwMdXUNTIGEBxEZAnqGBCZBlbhAb@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ              Input list
  ⁰             Literal 0
⊞               Push to list
      θ         Augmented list
     Ｅ          Mapped to
             θ  Augmented list
            ✂   Sliced from
              κ Current index
           Σ    Summed
          ⊗     Doubled
       ⁼        Equals
         θ      (Augmented) list
        Σ       Summed
    Σ           Sum of booleans
   Ｉ            Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Unfortunately in Charcoal `Sum([])` is not `0` so I have to ensure that there is always at least one element to sum.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>88</s> 82 bytes

<sup>-6 Bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($n)0..($x=$n.length)|%{$i+=+$z-eq($n[$_..$x]|measure -Su).sum;$z+=$n[$_]};$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCoMwEITvPoWHbTGYhGgNLUig79BjkeIhVkGtTSoVf549NYHqZZj9Zma711cqXcq6NlCIyXS5ypsAWsQoDWAQ0NJats9PiebDBFUoQhiJfK@NOzwohSGbG5nrXkmf3HpEdd@kMIbC5dmSQmUWzztC4V@DiDGGfRJxqxcrsQURS6w/M7T3MFllu3GMT3voduuMb4i7rxY58@ccmR8)

This seems like a very clumsy method but it got the job done. I'll try and revamp it in the future.

Comment: you can write `$i+=<predicate>` instead `if(<predicate>){$i++}`

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
s0GhYsE=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/YwD0jstjVtvi/S1RFyP9oQwMDAx0FXUNTEGkBIoxAAoYGJiC2uUEsF0gJUIEBmKlgpGAMFgKpUzA0BbFNQdoVIBSIHwsA)

Same approach as some other answers: prepend a zero, and check how often half the cumulative sum is equal to the total sum.

```
s   % Total sum of (implicit) input
0Gh % Prepend 0 to another copy of the input
Ys  % Cumulative sum
E=  % Check element-wise equality of 2*cumulative sum with total sum
s   % Sum number of `true` values
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>49</s> <s>45</s> 36 bytes

```powershell
(($args+0|%{2*($s+=$_)})-eq$s).count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/hCsIgFIX/@xSXdQstC7c1iiDYmwxZtoJRazoKtj37UsvIH5fj5zlXTnN/qlZfVF1PeIYj9BOlKNtKr8Qw75MlRb06YsFGtlYP1GxT3rubmUZCckrAHk5jDrEQgsM6ztzcu5E4EIut0zvBvtbEW51T/JiLc7AvaSA@6XdYkQWauov/5Cf@A4wwGGAOvWeoXo0qjTpxQGlrYfHBrdJdbSxY2La5hBnoppbGXG@VN0RIvx5XNyxhh5CMyDi9AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

Not as good as day 1. This one loses to Jelly

```
{~c₂+ᵐ=}ᶜ
```

### Explanation

```
{      }ᶜ   # Count the ways to:
 ~c₂        #   Split the input array in 2 ...
    +ᵐ      #   so that their sums ...
      =     #   are equal
```

Test suite:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahjuZJrRUFqcklqipWCUrl9SbmSjoJ7fgmYk/GobcOjpqZyJQUNEK9cSVPp4a7O2odbJ/yvrksGymgDmba1D7fN@f8/Ojra0MDAQEch3tAURFqACCOQgKGBCYhtbhALZMfqgNWBlBmABIyAGCgCZOgoGEMUgPgQzUCuKZBvABEzBZsNEgMzYiEagBJgJbEA)

Answer (score 1):

## bash, 52 bytes

```
IFS=+;for i in 0 $@;{((c+=2*(x+=i)=="$*"));};echo $c
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##JYzBCoMwEETvfsUgOSSKsLGVFkKgp0LPPYoHqykJiIIWWqj99nRtDzs7b4edW7v4@PRhcJhd22NY17qGGNA0Bv2ExT1QFHwwkPFyvtrc3KcZAWEEQZzMW8out2UmX7kNytpUZKlS5mNc5yeILqqtZ3RRExEKXbEceUomTXt2B0r0LyI2KLFj3HLoKtHV9oL/il8)

The trick: setting `IFS=+`, `"$*"` expands to a string where arguments are delimited by `+`, in arithmetic expression eval to the sum

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, <s>46</s> 35 bytes

```
f x=sum[1|a<-scanl(+)0x,a==sum x/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETv/Yo5tpjqJhrqwXyCX1CCLGKxmJRiFHrw36Nb28sw@3Zm7pwetxBy7jC59I6t/vCpTlceQrmpaFLsBGPaGZ8j9wMcIo/nC8rx2Q8vbNFVaAug1USkUGsrehQxAjQdxDfk1ZKSEK2nglHYr7@59OvYBdh5UMBs/rTW3hf5Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
1#.[:(={:-])0+/\@,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1oq00bKutdGM1DbT1Yxx0Yv9rcqUmZ@QrGCrYKqQpGBoYGCjEG5oCCQsgNgLyDA1MgCxzA4gyI5gyoCoDAxStQDljiIABVBHIAAVDU4igMUTQFGQ8lEJR/R8A)

### explanation

```
1 #. [: (= ({: - ])) 0 +/\@, ]

                     0     , ]  NB. prepend 0 to input...
                       +/\@     NB. and take the prefix sums...
     [:    ({: - ])             NB. then subtract that list
                                NB. from its final elm 
                                NB. (`{:`), giving the list
                                NB. of suffix sums...
     [: (= (      ))            NB. create a 1-0 list showing
                                NB. where the prefix sums 
                                NB. equal the suffix sums
1 #.                            NB. and take the sum.
```